# Is the limsup perserved under monotonically increasing functions?

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

I've done a bit of digging but I haven't found any sources to confirm that this is true.

Take $\limsup{\{x_n\}}=L$ and $f(x): D \to \mathbb{R}$ to be a continuous and monotonically increasing function such that $\{x_n\} \in D$. Does $\limsup{f(x_n)} = f(L)$?

I take it to be true because $f$ preserves order, and as there are only a finite number of terms greater than a given $L + \epsilon$ then after the application of the function there will still only be a finite number of terms greater than $f(L) + \epsilon$.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Let $x_n = 1-{1 \over n}$ and $f(x) = x + 1_{[1,\infty)}(x)$. Then $\lim_n x_n = 1, \lim_n f(x_n) = 1$, but $f(\lim_n x_n) = 2$.

Comment: How are you getting that the $lim{f(x_n) = 1}$, $f(x_n) = 2 - \frac{1}{n}$ implying that $lim(f(x_n)) = 2$ not $1$.

Comment: @EzTheBoss2 Have you encountered a step function $1_{[1,\infty)}(x)$ before?  (For each $n$, $1_{[1,\infty)}(x_n)=0$, so $f(x_n)=x_n$)

Comment: I’ve encounter the step function but not using that notation.

Comment: That does seem to be a valid counter example, what would happen if we force f to be continuous?

Comment: It's an indicator function, which is more general.  Common notations are either $1_A(x)$ or $\chi_A(x)$.  It equals $1$ if $x\in A$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for the nice counter example! I have added an additional stipulation to my question to force f to be continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting your question:

"Take $\limsup{\{x_n\}}=L$ and $f(x): D \to \mathbb{R}$ to be a continuous and monotonically increasing function such that $\{x_n\} \in D$. Does $\limsup{f(x_n)} = f(L)$?"

i.) Given that $f(x)$ is continuous and monotonically increasing has no logical connection to $\{x_n\} \in D$.

ii.) I am assuming that your question refers to $D$ bounded.

Thus:

Using Heine-Borel theorem:
$lim_{x\rightarrow L}f(x)$
exists and $lim_{x \rightarrow L}f(x)=M$ iff for every sequence $x_n\rightarrow L, x_n\neq L, \forall n\implies f(x_n)\rightarrow M$.

Now:

$f(x)$ is continuous in $D\implies 
lim_{x\rightarrow L}f(x)=f(L)=M$ by definition of continuity.

which is equivalent to:
$\forall (x_n)\rightarrow L \implies f(x_n)\rightarrow M$

Thus:
Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence with $limsup(x_n)=L$.

Then there exists a subsequence of $x_n$
Namely, $x_{n_k}$, s.t. $x_{n_k}\rightarrow L$.

And since $f(x)$ is continuous $lim f(x_{n_k})\rightarrow M$.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Where do you use $f$ is monotonically increasing?